# Tikz: Drawing tangent to S-shaped (logistic) function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to make a similar graph as given below but without x-axis labels.

[image]

This is what I got with the code given below:
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}%
    [
        %grid=major,     
        xmin=-6,
        xmax=6,
        axis x line=bottom,
        ytick={0,0.1,...,1},
        ymax=1.1
       % axis y line=middle,
    ]
        \addplot%
        [
            blue,%
            mark=none,
            samples=100,
            domain=-6:6,
        ]
        (x,{1/(1+exp(-x))});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm not able to get the tangent on the S-shaped curve and box around the figure as given in figure one without x-axis labels. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove ticks from top and right you can add `xtick pos=left` and  `ytick pos=left`.

You can define two coordinates on your plot with  `coordinate [pos=0.66] (A)` and  `coordinate [pos=0.7] (B)` after `addplot` command.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}%
    [
        %grid=major,     
        xmin=-6,
        xmax=6,
        xtick pos=left,
        ytick pos=left,
        ytick={0,0.1,...,1.1},
        ymax=1.1,
        yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/precision=1,
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill}
       % axis y line=middle,
    ]
        \addplot%
        [
            blue,%
            mark=none,
            samples=100,
            domain=-6:6,
        ]
        (x,{1/(1+exp(-x))})
        coordinate [pos=0.66] (A)
        coordinate [pos=0.7] (B);
        \coordinate (C) at (A|-B) ;
        \draw (A)--(C)node[midway,left]{\scriptsize $\beta \pi(a-\pi)$};
        \draw (B)--(C)node[midway,above]{\scriptsize $1$};
        \draw ($(A)!-1!(B)$)--($(B)!-1!(A)$);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @salim bou for your effort, time and help. Would appreciate if you guide how to get y-labels like `0.0, 0.1, ...,0.9, 1.0` rather than `0, 0.1, ...,0.9, 1`. Thanks again.

Comment: With `yticklabel style` you can modify format of numbers  with key `number format`,  code updated.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove the labels, then write

```
xticklabels={\empty}
```

If you wan to remove the ticks too, then add

```
xtick={\empty}
```

However, your graph appears slightly different than the image you posted in your question, so if you really want that kind of axes, remove or comment out this line

```
axis x line=bottom,
```

For drawing the tangent line, since it's only for illustration purpose, I placed a node along the plot using the `decorations.markings` library, and placed it somewhere where the south west and north east corners matched the plot the most, so placed a line along that diagonal, extending the two extremities, *et voilà*.

The nodes are added using labels, but you could use nodes too by using the decoration node as reference.

Finally, for setting the labels with a decimal, you can add the following code to your axis options:

```
y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=1,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
```

### Output

[image: example image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}%
    [
        %grid=major,     
        xmin=-6, xmax=6,
        ymax=1.1,
        ytick={0,0.1,...,1},       
        xtick={\empty},
        xticklabels={\empty},
        y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=1,
        /tikz/.cd
        },
    ]
        \addplot%
        [
            blue,%
            mark=none,
            samples=100,
            domain=-6:6,
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position 0.72 with {%
                    \node[minimum size=2.5mm, inner sep=0, 
                        label=90:{\scriptsize\sffamily 1}, 
                        label=180:{\scriptsize $\beta\pi(1-\pi)$}] (a) {};}
            },postaction=decorate
        ]
        (x,{1/(1+exp(-x))});
    \end{axis}
    \draw[blue, shorten <=-8mm, shorten >=-8mm] (a.south west) -- (a.north east);
    \draw[blue] (a.south west) -- (a.north west) -- (a.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alenanno for your answer. Would highly appreciate if you guide me how to get tangent in my figure 2.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I have a question: do you want the tangent in a specific point? What I mean is, is it "fake" or mathematically correct? Although I'm afraid it's not going to be easy to do in either case.

Comment: Tangent can be at any point. I need this for illustration purpose.

Comment: @MYaseen208 See edit.

Comment: Thanks @Alenanno for your effort, time and help. Would appreciate if you guide how to get y-labels like `0.0, 0.1, ...,0.9, 1.0` rather than `0, 0.1, ...,0.9, 1`. Thanks again.

Comment: @MYaseen208 See edit.

Answer (score 1):

For fun: `pstricks-add` can easily plot tangent lines at specific points on curves with the `\psplotTangent` command:

```
\documentclass[svgnames, border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{ pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\def\F{1/(1 + EXP(-x))}
\def\Fx{(EXP(-x))/((1 + EXP(-x))^2)}

\begin{document}

\psset{yunit=10cm, arrowinset=0.15, labelFontSize=\footnotesize, tickwidth =0.6pt}
\begin{pspicture*}(-7,-1)(6.1,1.06)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=frame, linecolor=SteelBlue, tickcolor=SteelBlue, labels=y, Dy=0.1, ticks=y, yticksize=-3pt 0pt, %xticksize=0pt -3pt,
    yDecimals=1,](-6,0)(-6,-0.06)(6,1.06)%(-6,0.06)
    \psset{linewidth=1.2pt, plotpoints=200, plotstyle=curve,algebraic, labelsep=0.5em}
    \psplot[linecolor =IndianRed]{-6}{6}{\F}%{1/(1 + EXP(-x))}%
    \psplotTangent[Derive=(\Fx), linewidth=0.6pt, linecolor=SteelBlue, showpoints]{2}{3}{\F}
    \psCoordinates[linestyle=none, linewidth=0.4pt, showpoints=false](*2 {\F})
    %\psset{origin = {0,-0.06}}
    \psaxes[ linewidth=0.6pt, linecolor=SteelBlue, tickcolor=SteelBlue, labels=x, Ox=-6, ticks=x, xticksize=0pt -3pt, xlabelPos =bottom](-6,-0.06)(-6,-0.06)(6,-0.06)%
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]