# Drawing a curve with vertical arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

That is what I've got so far, but I have no idea how to insert the arrow. I would really appreciate any kind of help! Thanks again to @marmot

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} 

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[-stealth] (-4,0) -- (-4,4.5);
\draw[blue] plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=-4:4] (\x,{2-2*tanh(1.5*(\x+1))}) node at (-1.3,3) [left]{G\"utefunktion}; 
\draw[-stealth] (-4.5,0) -- (4.5,0) node[below right]{$\mu$};          
 \draw[black,thick] (0.25,-0.5) -- (0.25,5) node at (0.25, -0.5)[below]{140};
 \draw[-latex] (0.5,4.5) -- (4,4.5) node[midway,above]{H0 Bereich};
 \draw[-latex] (-0.05,4.5) -- (-4,4.5) node[midway,above]{H1 Bereich};
\draw [red] (-4.2,0.5) -- (3,0.5) node at (-4.3,0.5) [left]{$\alpha$ = 0,05};
\draw [black] (-4.2,4) -- (4.5,4) node at (-4.2,4) [left]{1};    
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it shouldn't be so difficult. you need to define math expression for function first and show us what you trayed so far or simply wait for someone who will be willing to draw your image instead of you ;-)..,

Comment: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Comment: Looks like a `tanh`: `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=-4:4] (\x,{2-2*tanh(1.5*(\x+1))});
\draw[-stealth] (-4.5,0) -- (4.5,0);
\draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (0,4.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475602/drawing-a-function-without-knowing-its-definition

Comment: And you get my +1 for MWE.

Comment: From a -2 post to a +3 post: you can see the difference made by an MWE :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually with `\shade`, drawing the arrow is not really complicated. However, the text is not really readable IMHO.

In this answer, I don't use tang function, but a simple curve using `in` and `out`. This helps me calculate the coordinates for drawing the arrow.

Next time you ask a question, please make sure that you put some efforts into solving it in advance, otherwise it is very likely that your question is closed (like this one).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,>=stealth]
\draw[<->] (0,1.1) -- (0,0) coordinate (o) -- (1.75,0) coordinate (x) node[below] {$\mu$};
\path (0,1) coordinate (y);
\draw (-.02,1) node[left] {$1$}--(.02,1);
\draw (-.02,0) node[left] {$0$}--(0,0);
\draw[name path=alpha,red] (-.1,.05) node[left] {$\alpha=0.05$}--(1.75,.05);
\draw[name path=curve,blue,postaction={
    decorate,
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.5 with \coordinate (midarrow);,
        mark=at position 0.55 with \coordinate (nodename);
    }
}] (0,1) to[out=0,in=180] (1.5,0);
\path[name intersections={of=curve and alpha,by=inter}];
\draw (inter) -- (inter |- o) -- ++ (0,-.1) node[below] {$140$};
\draw (inter) -- (inter |- y) -- ++ (0,.2);
\draw (y) -- ++ (1.75,0);
\draw[->] ([shift={(-.02,.05)}]inter |- y) node[above left] {$H_1$-Bereich} -- ++ (-.5,0);
\draw[->] ([shift={(.02,.05)}]inter |- y) node[above right] {$H_0$-Bereich} -- ++ (.5,0);
\path[blue] (nodename) node[below left] {G\"utefunktion};
\path (o)--(y) node[midway,sloped,above,font=\footnotesize] {$g(\mu)=P(\text{Ablehnung von }H_0)$};
\shade[top color=yellow!60!black,bottom color=yellow] (midarrow) -- ++(.1,.1) --++(-.05,0) --++(0,.15) --++(-.1,0) --++(0,-.15) --++(-.05,0) --cycle;
\shade[top color=yellow,bottom color=yellow!60!black] ([shift={(.05,.25)}]midarrow) --++(0,.15) --++(.05,0) --++(-.1,.1) --++(-.1,-.1) --++(.05,0) --++(0,-.15) -- cycle;
\path[yellow!20!black] (midarrow) --++(0,.25) node {Some text};
\node at (0,1.25) {$H_0:\;\mu\ge\mu_0$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]